# How to separate label text respective to div?

Tags: css

I have a label defined where one half needs to be at left side and the other half of text needs to be on right side. How can I solve this so that the other half is pulled right?

I have added margin-right to get the text to pull at right but it's not consistent for other divs.

```
<div class="radio">
  <input class="radio-test" type="radio" value="3" checked="checked" name="test[id]" id="test_id">
  <label class="radio-label" for="test_id_1">
    Test of $12.0
    <span class="test-cost">Free</span>
  </label>
  <hr class="test-hr">
  <p class="test-message"></p><p>- First test message</p><p></p>
</div>
```

Expected Result:

[image]

Current Result:
[image]

How can I make text in above image i.e. 'Free' to appear on the right most side as shown on expected result? Also make it always consistent on other div such that the space from div is same across.

Comment: Have you tried to set the rule `float: right` for the class `test-cost` ?

Comment: did u try to put the label on a `width:80%;` or something like that and then `float:right` ur span inside

Comment: what does your CSS currently look like?

Comment: Please, add your css.

Comment: I agree with @MikeDiglio it would be nice to have the CSS, or even better, a JSFiddle or working snippet.

Comment: Thank you everyone. @RamondeVries's answer did the work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete working example with **JsBin**: https://jsbin.com/yafesuyola/1/edit?html,css,output

It uses **flexbox** with `justify-content: space-between`. I also added a `div` around the label and the input to keep them on the same line with 100% width.

```
<div class="radio">
  <div class="radio-and-label">
    <input class="radio-test" type="radio" value="3" checked="checked" name="test[id]" id="test_id">
    <label class="radio-label" for="test_id_1">
      Test of $12.0
      <span class="test-cost">Free</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <hr class="test-hr">
  <p class="test-message"></p><p>- First test message</p><p></p>
</div>
```

```
.radio {
  border: 2px solid #33c;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #e0eeff;
  color: #33c;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.radio-and-label {
  display: flex;
}

.radio-label {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.test-cost {
  text-align: right;
}

.test-hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0; 
}
```

[image]

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Clip the element to always be pinned to top right of the element?

```
.radio {
  position: relative;
}

.test-cost {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px; // or whatever px/rem/etc value that fits your need
}
```